# Manage unique fields insertion with hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm working on a JAVA project and need to insert an entity in my DB using Hibernate but the fields need to be inserted only once.

I have this ProjectEntity class that I need to insert to my database :

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class ProjectEntity extends PanacheEntity {
    private String projectname;
    private String projectkey;
}
```

My projectentity table looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE projectentity
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT project_pkey
            PRIMARY KEY,
    projectname TEXT,
    projectkey TEXT,
);
```

I tried to put the fields in the table as unique but obviously it is not enought as I get an error when I'm trying to insert the same fields and it blocks the execution of my program.

I want to know how can I manage the insertion of the project entity once when a new project is specified and then not do it again if the project already exists in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Column for every fields and set unique=true .

example :

```
@Column (name "projectname",nullable = false, unique = true )
private String projectname;
```